# Store all build artifacts in Jenkins

Tags: python, shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifacts

I have a Jenkins job named workspace_creation.

In this job, I am creating a directory with a build number and touching a file in it.
for eg.

```
mkdir ${BUILD_NUMBER}
cd ${BUILD_NUMBER}
touch test.12345.txt
```

In the end, I am using post-build actions and using "archive the artifacts" option to store the artifacts.

But......here's a catch

If I build the job again the previous artifacts get replaced by the new build artifact.
But I want all the old artifacts too, as in discard old build I have provided max 20 number to keep the artifacts.

Screenshot:

[image]

Giving the max artifact number to 20, still not able to get the old artifacts.
Is it the correct way or there is another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If we build the pipeline again, we can find our artifact in either of the following locations. Every time we build, the artifacts are stored in a separate directory named by its build number.

- `$JENKINS_HOME/yourjobname/branches/branchname/builds/yourbuildernumer/archive`
- `$JENKINS_HOME/yourjobname/builds/yourbuildernumer/archive`